# call a function which is declared in UIViewcontroller to AppDelegate with a ilustrated example

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

Is it possible to call a function which is on a UiviewController to appdelegate
Im using an Sdk which contains a group of custom controllers and controllers which can be subclassed

Example:

Suppose We have 2 viewcontrollers and appdelegate

viewController 1.h  which is in the sdk and can be subclassed

```
    @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
    @end
```

and second viewController
which is subbclass of firstViewController
ex:

```
 import# <customViewcontroller/customviewcontroller.h>
 @interface FirstViewController : FirstViewController

 @end
```

in custoviewcontroller there is a function who is named
    -(void)showChatForUserId(NSString)userId;

and in the SecondViewcontroller.m
i can get the right result if i call

```
[self showChatForUserId:self.targetUserId];
```

and in Appdelegate i import SecondViewController
My question is 
How can i possibly use the function [self showChatForUserId: ]
And userId comes from Push notification in appdelegate in the method

```
  -(UIApplication)application didReceiveRemoteNotifications(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {
      NSString userId = [userInfo valueForKey"uid"]; here comes the id which i can use in the showChatForUseId.
    }
```

how can i possibly call this function by creating some instance of SecondViewController in appdelegate and get

```
 [self ShowChatForUserID:userId];
```

in the didReceiveRemoteNotifications method of appDelegate.m

Thank You to anyone who possibly can help in this case. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bears a suspicious similarity to the exact same question asked earlier in the day.

First off some general advice, sit down for a few hours and read some of the first chapters of  an iOS book as you're floundering around, and even after getting the answer from your question you'll just continue to flounder without slowing down and getting some basic understanding under your belt.

Now

```
[self ShowChatForUserID:userId];
```

is not a function, the function is ShowChatForUserID:. Do you know what self means?

Before ShowChatForUserID can be called on an instance of SecondViewController their either 
a) has to already exist an object of that type when didReceiveRemoteNotifications is called or
b) some part of your program has to create one.

So some object has to either have previously created a SecondViewController (SVC) or now some object has to create one.

Which object should create it cannot be answered because we have no idea of what the overall design of your application is or should be with only the information supplied.

Applications have a root view controller (RVC) and the root view controller might *be* a SecondViewController, or the RVC might create an SVC, or the RVC might create another VC which in turn should be responsible for creating the SVC, or .....

The app delegate should post a notification (using NSNotificationCenter) to notify *something* that the push has been arrived and to send the push id to *something*.

*Something* might be the SVC if it already exists, or it might be the RVC, or it might be another VC.
If *something* is the SVC then it could call [self ShowChatForUserID:userId];
If *something* isn't the SVC then it might create the SVC and initialize it with the userId.

It is not possible to say what *something* should be because the answer to that depends upon the whole of how your application should be designed and architected.

This is the correct answer, if its not the nice simple answer that you can copy/paste right away into your code then sorry to disappoint you. If you don't understand it then don't post another question again a few hours later hoping to get another answer that you can copy/paste. Heed what I said right at the very top about books.

If somebody gives you some quick canned answer that you can apply immediately, their answer is quick hack bullshit.

(IF the RVC is the SVC then it would be possible for the app delegate to call a method on that class directly to tell it to show the chat for the user id, or if the RVC is not the SVC then it would still be possible for the app delegate to tell it to pass the message to show the chat to the SVC. But in a real app the RVC would not be the SVC, and the app delegate calling methods on the RVC which get passed down is not good).